# ARM Cortex-A9 - __libc_init_array with undefined instruction

Tags: c++, gcc, arm, embedded, linaro

I'm using Linaro GCC version 6.3.1 to compile my C++ program.

When debugging instruction by instruction, in eclipse (Xilinx SDK 2017.1), I get an undefined instruction fault at the instruction address 0x1090d8 as below:
[image]

This instruction is part of the __libc_init_array function which is called before my main.

I already tried calling the arm-eabi-g++ with the linker flags -mthumb and -marm but the result is the same. I always get the same fault (despite at different locations) and I'm not able to jump to my main function.

I'm using a Zybo Zynq-7000 with two Cortex-A9 processors

Thanks

Comment: Do not run the program before setting a break point on `start`. Use `b start` and then use `run`.  This should break immediately before any libc startup code is run.  Some static constructor and or other pre-main code is causing a memory or stack corruption.  The function may be `_start` depending.

Comment: @artlessnoise Forgot to mention that I also use the -nodefaultlibs -nostdlib options so I think I don't call the start function or libc code.

Comment: Ah, but that start code initializes C++ static constructors and other things (zero BSS, etc).  If you have `linaro`, you use Linux?  Then your executable entry point is traditionally 'start'.  Use `readelf -h $1 | grep  Entry` to check what your start is.